# Powershell with -ArgumentList

Tags: powershell, syntax, osisoft

I want to run following command in Powershell: AFImport.exe

> [https://docs.osisoft.com/bundle/pi-server/page/afimport-utility.html][1]

Syntax Example #1

```
AFImport "\\AFServer\database" /File:"C:\Filename.xml" /P
```

Now I made following code:

```
Set-Location -Path "$Env:pihome64\AF"
$xml = "C:\Temp\test.xml"
$AF = "\\AFtest\AF-test"
$log = "C:\Temp\log.txt"
Start-Process AFImport.exe -ArgumentList '$AF','File:$xml','/P' -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput $log
```

When executting the script the CMD window an runs AFImport.exe but nothing is shown and closes after a few seconds.

What syntac error do I have?

Comment: use double quotes for *interpolation* of your variables to occur.

Comment: If you want string interpolation, you need to use double-quotes.  e.g. `'File:$xml'` => `"File:$xml"`.  Also, it looks like you are missing a `/` from that parameter: `"/File:$xml"`

Comment: so correct command would be:
Start-Process AFImport.exe -ArgumentList '$AF',"/File:$xml",'/P' -Wait
no results, same windows opens but closes after seconds